# Add markers to Panorama in Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, panoramas

I already have an android app, It downloads a 360-degree panoramic image from the internet and displays inside the app using the [PanoramaApi](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/panorama/package-summary). This is all nice; I get the finger pan feature and the gyroscope based movement feature.

But I want more features. I want to be able to put markers inside the image and when clicked; I want to be able to move to a new Panoramic image inside the same viewer. Much like the [live-in tour](https://www.commonfloor.com/live-in-tour) feature of [CommonFloor](https://www.commonfloor.com/). They also have the same feature in their [Android App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.commonfloor).

My goal is to create the same functionality.

What I have achieved so far is to display one panorama with [PanoramaApi](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/panorama/package-summary). Here is my effort so far on [Github](https://github.com/ishanatmuz/PanoramaDisplay). My goal is to add markers and move from one panorama to another. And since I am currently displaying panorama using an Intent from the PanoramaAPI; I highly doubt that I will be able to add markers using this method.

There must be a better method for doing this.

I thought of using Unity, as [Cardboard SDK for unity](https://developers.google.com/cardboard/unity/) will also let me add Google Cardboard in future.

I don't want the user to install two separate APKs instead, I want the Unity to be embedded inside the current android app. It is documented [here](https://github.com/TTimo/unity-android-example). One trick to display panorama images is documented [here](http://zhvillues.tumblr.com/post/126331275376/creating-a-360-viewer-using-unity-3d). However, I still have some problems with this.

1. How can I add markers to this?
2. If I add the markers somehow, how to embed that information within the panorama jpg file? (Can I do this without embedding the info as meta-data in the file, but instead saving that meta-data in a separate file (JSON/XMl or something else))?
3. How to pass the URLs for the panoramic jpegs and possible meta-data files, from the android activity to Unity?

I know about [krpano](http://krpano.com/), but it is for the web. I want a similar solution but for android.

Are there better libraries or SDKs that will enable me to achieve this? If not how can I communicate between Android and Unity?